# Declarations and global reference variables for several files

Tags: variables, runtime, ocaml, declaration

My folder contains several files, which are compiled in this order: `global.ml`, `zone.ml`, `abs.ml`, `main.ml`

`global.ml` contains some reference variables (e.g. `let g1 = ref 0`) for all the files.

In `zone.ml` there is a declaration `let f = !g1`.

In `abs.ml`, there is `g1 := 5`, which will be run by `main` in the beginning of run-time, I consider it as an initialization of `g1` given the real run-time context.

Later `main` will call `Zone.f`. Curiously, what I realize is that it takes `f = 0` instead of `f = 5`.

Do you think this behavior is normal? If so, what should I change, to make it take the current value of `!g1` into account?

PS: Maybe one solution is to make a function `let f v = v` in `zone.ml` then let `main` call `Zone.f !g1`. But I have several global reference variables as `g1` in `global.ml`, I hope they could be valid over all the files and functions, and I don't want to get them involved in the signature of a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are basically concerned with the order of evaluation of the top-level values in your modules.  The order in which this happens isn't related to the order that you *compile* the files, but rather the order that they appear when you *link* the files.

If you ignore the module boundaries, if you link the files in the order you give, what you have is like this:

```
let g1 = ref 0
let f = !g1
let () = g1 := 5
```

It shouldn't be surprising that `f` has the value 0.

Note that your `main` is not necessarily the first thing that happens at runtime.  Top-level values are evaluated in the order the files appear when you link them.  Very commonly, `main` is the *last* top-level thing to happen (because its file is usually the last one).

(Also note that having a `main` at all is just a convention, presumably adopted by former C programmers like me.  There's no requirement to have a function named `main`.  OCaml just evaluates the top-level values in order.)

**Edit:**

It's difficult to say how to restructure your code without knowing more about it.  The essence of your problem appears to be that you define `f` as a top-level immutable value in `zone.ml` but you want its value to follow `g1`, which is a mutable value.

The simplest suggestion would be to remove the definition of `f` from `zone.ml` and replace it everywhere in the file with `!g1`.

If you want to retain the name `f` at the top level in `zone.ml`, you have to redefine it as something other than an immutable value.  A function is the most obvious choice:

```
let f () = !g1
```

Then you would replace uses of `f` in `zone.ml` by `f ()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you explained why it happens, but you did not explain how to solve it... I can't change the order of compilation of these files, what else can I do?

Comment: I added **Edit** with some suggestions.  But it's hard to know what to suggest without knowing more about your code.